# Arc length and position vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, arc-length

Suppose $r(t) = (x(t),y(t),z(t))$ be the position vector of a point $(x,y,z)$ is $dr/dt$ and $ds/dt$ the same? Where $s$ is the arc length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  $r(t)$ is a vector and $s(t)$ is a scalar.  Their derivatives have the same number of components as the functions, so they cannot be the same.  You  do have $\frac {ds}{dt}=\left|\frac {dr}{dt}\right|$

Comment: In this case, why are they the same?

Comment: Notice the magnitude signs on the right.  That makes the right into a scalar, which is the speed the point is traveling.  The distance covered, $s$, is just the integral of the speed.

Comment: Yes I see that one is a vector and another is a scalar. I wanted to know conceptually why they are the same. Or to put it this way, how can I visualise it?

Comment: I think the best way is to recognize they are both the speed of motion at any time, without reference to direction.  They are both what the speedometer on your car would read.